# Update several elements via Ajax from PHP array result

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to generate some invoices based on user's input (date selection). That is something like this:

1. The `invoice.php` file would let the user select a date from a form, and based on that selection the contents of the invoice (like amount, customer, etc.) on that same page  would be updated through Ajax.
2. The `ajaxInvoice.php` would generate a MySQL query and in the end create an array with the corresponding table row based on date selection and merchant (unique row).

---

`invoice.php`

```
...

<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('field_1');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
    var merchant = document.getElementById('merchant').value;
    var queryString = "?date=" + date + "&merchant=" + merchant;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajaxInvoice.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

//-->
</script>

...

<form name="invoiceDate">
<input type="hidden" id="merchant" value="<?php echo $merchant; ?>" />
Date: <select id="date">
<option>2013-07-23</option>
<option>2013-07-25</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="ajaxFunction()" value="Select Date" />
</form>

...

<div id="field_1">FIELD 1</div>

...

<div id="field_2">FIELD 2</div>

...

<div id="field_3">FIELD 3</div>

...
```

---

`ajaxInvoice.php`

```
include_once('includes/db.php');

$merchant = $_GET['merchant'];
$date = $_GET['date'];

$merchant = mysql_real_escape_string($merchant);
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($date);

$query = "SELECT * FROM settlements WHERE datePayment = '$date' AND merchant = '$merchant'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

---

I was wondering if I could have access to that array this way:

```
echo $array[0]['fieldName'];
```

and update selected elements on the page based on different row fields. Not sure if `getElementById` or `getElementByName` should be used.

My question would be how to actually access the php array within the script part and also within the rest of the page, so that I can update the various div elements with the corresponding data obtained from the DB query after the user selects the date from the form.

In fact, if *only* one div has to be updated, the code works just fine, but I don't know how to extend the logic to update more than one div.

Any help or hints on the syntax or code logic would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What is your question? Your post is very long and I see no `?` anywhere.

Comment: I would use a JS library such as JQuery for your JS so you can simplify your code.  I would also use `json_encode` in your php to return your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use JSON:

PHP at the server: `echo json_encode($array)`

JavaScript on the client: `var response = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText)`

Implemented:

`invoice.php`

```
...
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        var response = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);

        // Now you can use:
        response[0]['fieldName'];

        // Like this
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('field_1');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = response[0]['field_1'];                
    }
}
...
```

`ajaxInvoice.php`

```
...
$array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}

// Encode to JSON
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It worked very well. I was able to use multiple occurrences of ajaxDisplay by referencing different fieldNames and get the desired results in different elements with different ID's.